# How can I improve a question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've started twice of the bounty of my question

- [How to implement a dealer class without storing a deck of cards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619574/how-to-implement-a-dealer-class-without-storing-a-deck-of-cards)

I provide the information as possible as I understand, and even made a animated graphics for expressing. I tried hard to make people understand my question, but somehow I still be asked that like *what is your question*.

Thus I'm thinking that I need help to better expressing the question.

Is there something more to do to make it clear to people?

Comment: you can post in the c# chat channel and ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If John Skeet can't see the question, you've got something wrong.

I'm not a C# programmer, however, it looks like what you need, is a big fat:

## In summary:

At the bottom of your question, which basically says:

1. I don't know how to calculate the permutionIndex
2. I need an algorithm which computes one with **minimal cost**
3. I need algorithm(s) which compute(s) the correct permutationIndex to indicate the current sequence of cards

(Essentially, That's just summing up what you've said in the question + some answers to people who wanted clarification)

You may also want to add in with more clarity why you want to do this with this method or some such.

**EDIT:** What I mean is, you need a summary at the end of your posts to outline the main points of the question. For example, If I posted concerning some algorithm or other, and it was a rather lengthy post, **the question can get lost on the background information**. What you need to do is just tell the viewers in short what you want to get done. People aren't getting the question, because the question is getting lost in all the information. If you can put a nice clear explanation of what you actually want to get done, it might go a long way.

Comment: Errrrm... `TL;DR`. ;-)

Comment: @KenKin, how to put it in your question?

Comment: @KenKin, what I'm trying to say is, what you need is a summary at the bottom of the question, summing up what you've wanted. **Don't** shorten the rest of the question, because it's extra information that may be required to solve the question. I'll edit my answer with what I mean.

Comment: @KenKin, my latest edit explains it better, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Bernie: Is it better now?

Comment: @KenKin, much better. You may want to change TL;DR to in summary though, as I did in my example. Seems to be more effective

Comment: @Bernie: Thank you very much! I'm not changin tldr, because there them are. Summary is at the begining.

Comment: @Ken.kin, oh I see now! Didn't see the start of the post, that's much better. Now all we have to do is wait to see if you can get any good replies now people know the question.